# Why was my self-answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I recently answered my own question but my answer was deleted promptly for being 'additional information' rather than an answer. Here's the question:

[Different uses of 'almost sure'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455375/different-uses-of-almost-sure)

And my answer was:

> They are equivalent.
>
> (Thanks to Did for the comment.)

One of the reviewers was kind enough to comment on my answer and said:

> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

From my perspective, I'm pretty sure the contents of my answer were about as direct an answer to the question as is possible. I don't see how it could be construed as mere 'additional information'. I can understand if Did should get the credit for the response, but given that he only posted as a comment I thought I would formalise it into an answer.

Why was the answer deleted?

Comment: I've voted to undelete, but if you're just quoting verbatim, it might be a bit more acceptable to set the answer CW.

Comment: Deleting the ansnwer is a mistake, but undeleting it now seem pointless, as there is already a strictly better answer.

Comment: In my opinion, if a question can be answered by a trivial three word answer (or just by "yes" or "no"), it usually better to put that as a comment (so the OP can delete the question). If it is necessary to put it as an answer, IMHO it should be a community wiki answer.  There is no reason for a trivial self-answer - just blush, delete the question, and move  on.

Comment: I also made a self-answer on another question, but this time the question got closed.

Answer (score 8):

I *guess* it was deleted because it's just an assertion without any elaboration or reasoning. Thus it's not a very good answer.

Still, the assertion does answer the question, and I think the reviewers made a mistake here.